# Flask migrate is not creating a table

Tags: python, database, flask, migration, microservices

I have this in my **product_api/models.py**

```
from . import db
from datetime import datetime


class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    slug = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    image = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=False, nullable=True)
    date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    date_updated = db.Column(db.DateTime, onupdate=datetime.utcnow)

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'name': self.name,
            'slug': self.slug,
            'price': self.price,
            'image': self.image
        }
```

I run **db init** and **db migrate** After the migrate command I get this message `UserWarning: Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set. Defaulting SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to "sqlite:///:memory:".` However few lines below it says I`NFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'product'`

I check MySQL database manually and sure enough, the table is not there, and I cannot reach my API endpoint.

I can see that the migration has created something in the **migration file**

```
revision = '66be5d817908'
down_revision = None
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None


def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('product',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('name', sa.String(length=255), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('slug', sa.String(length=255), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('price', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('image', sa.String(length=255), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('date_added', sa.DateTime(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('date_updated', sa.DateTime(), nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id'),
    sa.UniqueConstraint('name'),
    sa.UniqueConstraint('slug')
    )
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_table('product')
```

Here is my **run.py**

```
from application import create_app, db
from application import models
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = create_app()
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5002)
```

I have run through this exact scenario when creating my other micro-service with another database and had no issue whatsoever with migration creating tables. I looked into adding `db.create_all()` to my **run.py** but it didn't really work. I tried dropping the database and starting all over again, that didn't work either. I'm very confused why the first micro-service was working and this one is causing these issues.

EDIT 1 - Here is my **config.py**

```
# config.py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv


dotenv_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '.env')
if os.path.exists(dotenv_path):
    load_dotenv(dotenv_path)


class Config:
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False


class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    ENV = "development"
    DEBUG = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://kkan@localhost:3306/product';
    SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = True


class ProductionConfig(Config):
   pass
```

It looks the same as with my other microservice that works.

Comment: are you sure you set the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI in the app.config *before* you instantiated the db object?

Comment: I've added my config.py to the edit if you would like to take a look

Comment: Related debugging suggestions for this issue: [Flask-Migrate not creating tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323990/flask-migrate-not-creating-tables)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got it working.

Turns out my **CONFIGURATION_SETUP** was set to `"config.ProductionConfig"` instead of `"config.DevelopmentConfig"`